# How to wait for serial input in raw (noncanonical) mode?

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port

This program runs on PC and I want him wait until there are data available on serial connection from Arduino, and display them. If Arduino don't send anything, I want the program to wait indefinitely.

What happens, is that I've got only `Resource temporarily unavailable` messages.

After kind help from **Kurt Stutsman** here is a working program that waits for binary input from serial connection, (from the Arduino in this case).

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <fcntl.h>    // File control definitions
#include <termios.h>  // POSIX terminal control definitions
#include <unistd.h>   // UNIX standard function definitions

using namespace std;


int connect(const char* serialport)
{
    struct termios toptions;
    int fd;

    fd = open(serialport, O_RDWR );

    if (fd == -1)  {
        return -1;
    }

    if (tcgetattr(fd, &toptions) < 0)
        return -1;

    speed_t brate = B9600; //9600 bauds
    cfsetospeed(&toptions, brate);
    cfmakeraw(&toptions);
    toptions.c_cc[VMIN]  = 1; //I want read to wait for the input
    toptions.c_cc[VTIME] = 0; //indefinitely, until it arrives. Byte after byte.

    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &toptions);
    if( tcsetattr(fd, TCSAFLUSH, &toptions) < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    return fd;
}


int main() {
    int fd = connect("/dev/ttyACM0");
    if (fd==-1)
    {
        cout<<"Error in opening serial port\n";
        cout<<strerror(errno)<<'\n';
        return -1;
    }
    while(true)
    {
        uint8_t b=0;
        int ret=read(fd, &b, 1);
        if (ret == 1)
        {
            cout<<"received byte "<<int(b)<<'\n';
        } else if (ret == 0)
        {
            cout<<"EOF\n";
        } else
        {
            cout<<strerror(errno)<<'\n';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can test it with this simple Arduino C++ code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);        // connect to the serial port
}

void loop()
{
    Serial.write(uint8_t(42));
    delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Finding out what `errno` is in the `ERROR!` case would be very helpful. You can also use `strerror()` function to get a human-readable string for the `errno` value..

Comment: @KurtStutsman Thank you for comment. I get `Unknown error -1`...

Comment: That's not the `errno` value. `read()` returns `-1` on error, but the actual error is identified by the value of the global variable `errno`.

Comment: @KurtStutsman update: OK. The serial opens OK (I just forgot to connect the Arduino :-D) ), and the error reads "Resource temporarily unavailable".

Comment: @KurtStutsman I've updated the question according to your suggestion. I've got `Resource temporarily unavailable`. Why doesn't program wait for bytes to arrive?

Comment: You're getting `EAGAIN` from read(). This is because you're opening the device with `O_NONBLOCK`. Try removing that option.

Comment: @KurtStutsman Yes, that worked fantastically!! When I was reading manual for `open` I understood, that the `O_NONBLOCK` concerned only *opening* the stream, not reading it. My fault. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Your program needs to initialize the termios structure (before it starts to modify its contents) by calling **tcgetattr()**.  BTW reading a byte at a time is inefficient use of a syscall.  Just because VMIN is 1 does not restrict you to reading/requesting just one byte.

Comment: @sawdust Thank you. I've corrected my question/answer.